# Count the frequency that a combination occurs in a Dataframe column - Apriori algorithm

Tags: python, dataframe, count, frequency, apriori

I have a problem to search the correct solution of the frequency of a combination.

This my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

list = [1,20,1,50]

combinations = []
for i in itertools.combinations(list ,2):
    combinations .append(i)

data = pd.DataFrame({'products':combinations})

data['frequency'] = data.groupby('products')['products'].transform('count')

print data

The out is:

    products  frequency
0   (1, 20)     1
1    (1, 1)     1
2   (1, 50)     2
3   (20, 1)     1
4  (20, 50)     1
5   (1, 50)     2
```

The problem is (1, 20) and (20, 1), the frequency puts 1 but are the same combination and has to be 2, Is there any method with the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by a modification on the column by using applyand lambda

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

list = [1,20,1,50]

combinations = []
for i in itertools.combinations(list ,2):
    combinations .append(i)

data = pd.DataFrame({'products':combinations})

data['frequency'] = data.groupby(data['products'].apply(
    lambda i :tuple(sorted(i))))['products'].transform('count')

print (data)
```

The output will be

```
     products  frequency
0   (1, 20)          2
1    (1, 1)          1
2   (1, 50)          2
3   (20, 1)          2
4  (20, 50)          1
5   (1, 50)          2
```